# Proof clarification request: boundedness of operator (related to finite-dimensional vector spaces).

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have actually asked this question on MSE [(here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568823/proving-the-inverse-of-an-application-is-continuous), and the answer given used the compactness of the unit ball. After doing some search, I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867120/is-my-proof-correct-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-spaces) (it looks like mine is a duplicate of this one) and this (apparently) doesn't use the compactness  of the unit ball.

**Context.** On trying to prove that every finite-dimensional normed space is topologial isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, we define a generic normed space $E = (E,\|\cdot\|_E)$ such that $\dim(E)=n \in \Bbb N.$ Define
$$
T:\mathbb{R}^n\to E\\
x\mapsto x_1\delta_1+\dots x_n\delta_n
$$
where $B_E=\{\delta_1,\dots,\delta_n\}$ is an algebraic basis for $E$.

Although, the proof provided here isn't very clear (or detailed) to me (I am new to functional analysis). I am specifically talking about the part where the OP proves that $T^{-1}$ is bounded (or continuous).

**Step $\mathbf{1.}$** Assuming $T^{-1}$ is not bounded: here, the OP states:

> Suppose by contradiction that $T^{-1}$ is not bounded. Then, there exists
> $$
> (y_n)_n\subset E:\qquad \frac{\|T^{-1}y_n\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}}{\|y_n\|_{E}}>n\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}
> $$

And I can't figure how one would come up with such a sequence. My line of thought is as follows: If $T^{-1}$ is not bounded, then
$$ \forall c>0, \exists v \in E, \quad \|T^{-1}v\|_{\Bbb R^n} > c\|v\|_E $$
I understand that, in particular, we can pick $c=n$ and it follows that
$$ \exists v \in E\, : \, \|T^{-1}v\|_{\Bbb R^n} > n\|v\|_E \Leftrightarrow \frac{\|T^{-1}v\|_{\Bbb R^n}}{\|v\|_E} > n, \quad \text{ for $v \neq 0_E.$} $$
Well, obviously here $v \neq 0_E$ isn't a problem since $\|T^{-1}0_E\|_{\Bbb R^n} = 0$ which doesn't satisfy the strict inequality.

Now, how does the OP comes up with a infinite sequence? As far as I am concerned, it could be only one point $v \in E$ that satisfies the inequality... Basically, how is the sequence $(y_n)_n$ defined here?

**Step $\mathbf{2.}$** After this, the OP defines a new sequence just like I show below:

> Consider
> $$
> x_n:=\frac{T^{-1}y_n}{\|T^{-1}y_n\|_{E}},\quad (x_n)_n\subset\mathbb{R}^n
> $$
> We have
> $$
> \|x_n\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=1\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}
> $$

I have no problem understanding this part (I believe the OP made a mistake and it should be $\|T^{-1}y_n\|_{\Bbb R^n}$ in the denominator).

**Step $\mathbf{3.}$** The next step in the proof from the OP is presented below.

> but
> $$
> \|Tx_n\|_{E}<\frac{1}{n}\quad\forall n
> $$
> This is a contradiction since $T$ is injective.

Here, I understand that, since the sequence $(x_n)_n$ is bounded $(\|x_n\|_{\Bbb R^n} = 1 \Rightarrow \|x_n\|_{\Bbb R^n} \leqslant 1)$, then by the [Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem](https://unacademy.com/content/csir-ugc/study-material/mathematical-sciences/bolzano-weierstrass-theorem/) there is a convergent subsequence to some element $x$. But, from here, I don't know how to reproduce the inequality above.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please make your questions as self contained as possible. What is $T$? What is the context?

Comment: I am sorry, the context is fully in the other question I linked - I will try to put some of it in this question.

Comment: You get an infinite sequence by varying $n$. A priori the sequence might not be injective, but that doesn't matter (it's academic, since it doesn't exist)

Comment: Yup... I just realized: for each $n \in \Bbb N$, we have at least one element $v$ that satisfies the inequality. Thanks for your help. Now only the last part is making me confused.

Comment: About injectivity? Or about the inequality?

Comment: Firsly, about the inequality: how do we get to the inequality the OP presents?

Comment: (You also can't use the same $v$ for all $n$ since $\mathbb{R}$ has the archimedean property, but for the purpose of the proof it wouldn't matter anyway.)

Comment: If $\|T^{-1}y_n\|/\|y_n\|>n,\|Tx_n\|=\|y_n\|/\|T^{-1}y_n\|<1/n$

Comment: By the way, it can be directly shown that any linear map between finite dimensional vector spaces is continuous just by (crudely) bounding based off of the matrix entries. You might feel like this is simpler

Comment: Oh, it might be ill-advised to name both the index of the sequences and the dimension  of the vector spaces $n$, just noticed

Comment: @FShrike I understood the part of the inequality. Now to the contradiction itself: Where does it exaclty comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interests of not answering in the comments...

- Really, you are trying to show any finite dimensional vector space $E$ is (linearly) isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{\dim E}$. This is stronger than, and more important than, mere homeomorphism. I use $\dim E$ so as not to overload the letter "$n$", which you did in your post
- If such $v$ exist for all $n$, you can just let $y_n$ be such a $v$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$, there is no problem there. It is impossible that $(y_n)$ is (eventually) constant, since there are always $n>\|v\|$ (this is the Archimedean property mentioned in the comments) but it doesn't matter at all for the proof. *You just want a bag of vectors with arbitrarily large $T^{-1}$-image*: the size of the bag (how many distinct elements) is irrelevant, though necessarily it is countably infinite
- $\|T^{-1}y_n\|$ is nonzero by definition, for all $n$, so the vector: $$x_n:=\frac{T^{-1}y_n}{\|T^{-1}y_n\|}$$Is well defined. Note: $$Tx_n=\frac{TT^{-1}y_n}{\|T^{-1}y_n\|}=\frac{y_n}{\|T^{-1}y_n\|}$$So: $$\|Tx_n\|=\frac{\|y_n\|}{\|T^{-1}y_n\|}<\frac{1}{n}$$By taking reciprocals for the definition inequality for the $(y_n)$
- The unit sphere of $\Bbb R^{\dim E}$, $S$, wherein the $(x_n)$ reside, is compact. If you already know $T$ is continuous, then $TS$ is known to be compact and, in particular, closed in $E$ ($E$ has a metric this Hausdorff topology). As the $Tx_n\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ in $TS$, $0$ is an element of $TS$. But that implies $T\alpha=0$ for some $\alpha\in S$, and as $\|\alpha\|=1\neq0$, $\alpha\neq0$ and $T$ has a nontrivial kernel. It follows that $T$ is *not* injective, which is a contradiction. <s>It's late and I'm tired, so I can't think of a non-topological way to argue this right now (I think that's what you want), sorry</s>
- Update: Your Bolzano-Weierstrass mention was apt. There is an accumulation point $\alpha$ of $(x_n)$, and if you already know $T$ is continuous you can say: $Tx_{n_k}\to T\alpha$ along some subsequence, but the $Tx_n\to0$ thus $T\alpha=0$ since limits are unique (the underlying topologies are $\rm T1$). This contradicts the injectivity of $T$. Note: this is topological in secret, since we still use continuity ideas and the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem (and the Heine-Borel theorem) are just shadows of the general theorem: "A metric space (e.g. $S$) is sequentially compact iff. it is compact iff. it is complete and totally bounded." You can verify $S$ is compact via the last criterion
- That every linear map *out of* a finite dimensional linear space is continuous is much more easily seen (in my opinion) by crudely bounding the matrix entries. This argument involves essentially no topology, and broadly goes like this: fix a $T:U\to V$ where $U$ has dimension $n$ and $V$ is an arbitrary vector space (real, but may have infinite dimension). Fix an orthonormal vector basis $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$, for $U,V$ respectively. By finitude, there is a finite constant $K=\max(\|Te_i\|;i=1,2,\cdots,n)$. Any $x$ in the unit sphere $S$ of $U$ is expressible as $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i e_i$ for some scalars $(\lambda_i)$ - $\|Tx\|\le K\sum_{i=1}^n|\lambda_i|$ follows from the triangle inequality and the definition of $K$. Note that: $$1=\|\lambda_1e_1+\cdots+\lambda_ne_n\|=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2$$Which is just the general Pythagorean identity (I picked $(e_i)$ orthonormal... e.g. appeal to Gram-Schmidt). Clearly, each $\lambda_i$ is less than or equal to $1$ in magnitude - so: $$\|Tx\|\le nK$$You can do better and bound by $\sqrt{n}$ from Cauchy-Schwarz. This is also very similar to how you prove any two norms are equivalent in finite dimensions.

Comment: What is the argument behind "The unit sphere of $E$, $S$ is compact"? I understand that it is closed and bounded and this implies it is compact since $E$ is a finite dimensional normed space. But I am supposed to prove this equivalence of compactness based of this result, so it makes no sense to use it here

Comment: @roro I made a typo: I meant for $S$ to be the unit sphere of $\Bbb R^{\dim E}$ (though, you could use the general Heine-Borel theorem applied directly to $E$, mimicking the total-boundedness proof I gave in the other post, to avoid being circular) but if you aren’t comfortable with that, there’s another bullet point extending your Bolzano-Weierstrass idea.

Comment: Thanks. By the way - is there something similar to the *Heine-Borel* theorem in the complex case? Can we affirm the unitary sphere of $\Bbb C^n$ is compact aswell without  using normed space theory?

Comment: @roro Absolutely. I refer you again to what I call the general Heine-Borel-Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. A proof can be found in e.g. Royden's real analysis. It says that for *any metric space $X$* whatsoever, including $\Bbb C^n$, a subset $C\subseteq X$ is compact iff. it is complete and totally bounded iff. it is sequentially compact. Now, just as with $\Bbb R^n$, it is not too hard to show bounded subsets of $\Bbb C^n$ are totally bounded, and it is very quick to show that closed subsets are complete. Thus closed bounded subsets are compact (... and this is iff.)

Comment: @roro All 'sequentially compact' means, if you don't know, is essentially Bolzano-Weierstrass. Any sequence whatsoever has at least one accumulation point. Bolzano-Weierstrass is this statement for bounded sequences in $\Bbb R$, but you get that for free by considering the sequence within some bounded box $[-M,M]$ and using sequential compactness

Comment: I think I understand. Now a bit more related to your first idea (the bullet refering to the compactness of the unit sphere): It is not clear to me why $T(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ in $TS.$ Also not clear why this implies $T\alpha = 0$, for some $\alpha \in S$. Can you make this a bit more detailed for me please?

Comment: @roro The post you referenced showed: $\|T(x_n)\|<\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. That means $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T(x_n)\|=0$. Now, every $x_n$ is in $S$, so every $T(x_n)$ is in $TS$. That justifies "$T(x_n)\to0$ in $TS$". $TS$ is closed, so the fact that a sequence from within $TS$ - namely, the sequence $(T(x_n))_n$ - converges to zero implies zero is in $TS$. All elements of $TS$ are of the form $T(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in S$, so that means $T\alpha=0$ for at least one $\alpha\in S$. Critically, $\alpha$ is nonzero. Hence we get a lack of injectivity, since $T0=0$.

Comment: I see... I think I understood mostly everything. Now, going back to the Bolzano-Weierstrass bullet, I (believe) I understand everything but the fact that $\alpha$ has to be an accumulation point of $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}.$ Where does this conclusion comes from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140597/discussion-between-fshrike-and-roro).

Comment: @roro Chat doesn’t work on my phone. You used compactness of $S$ where you assumed that the continuous function $f$ had a minimum on $S$, in two ways: since $S$ is compact, $f(S)$ is also compact. A compact subset of a real subspace is bounded, so it has a real supremum and infimum. Moreover the compact subset is closed, so it *contains* its extrema and we can meaningfully talk about the minimum $c\in f(S)$.

Comment: but can't I just guarantee the existence of the minimum on $S$ using Weierstrass theorem? Since $f$ is continuous and $S$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: @roro this is not really a counterpoint, since the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem applies to a subset of the reals iff. that subset is compact! (sequential compactness is equivalent to topological compactness for metric spaces)

Comment: so... What's the necessity of mentioning that $S$ is compact? I still don't understand it... Why isn't closedness and boundedness enough? I understand it is equivalent but why even mention it ?

Comment: @roro Closedness and boundedness is enough. It wouldn’t surprise me if an author claimed: “… $f$ attains some minimum $c$ …” without further explanation, because it is common for authors to omit background details. However if you feel like you should give a reason, you can argue with compactness and it is very clean and quick (generalised extreme value theorem). In fact, Bolzano-Weierstrass doesn’t immediately give you that a minimum exists, you have to work a little harder. But the two are indeed equivalent

Comment: What exactly is the theorem that guarantees that $f$ continuous on $S$ compact $\Rightarrow$ $f$ has a minimum on $S$ ?

Comment: @roro I explained that where I wrote: “chat doesn’t work on my phone…” but if you don’t like that explanation, feel free to search for “(generalised) extreme value theorem”, “compact extreme value”, etc.

Comment: I see, I got the idea! Just one more thing: When we directly say $S$ is compact, we mean it is closed and bounded (and thus, compact), right?

Comment: @roro Sure ${}{}{}$